# Get Event Count by Event Name and User ID using Google Analytics Data API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I would like to retrieve data from Google Analytics Data API. Endpoint is:

[https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/{property_id}:runReport](https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/%7Bproperty_id%7D:runReport)

I would like to get report of number of events per event_name and username (from user_properties), what is the metric and dimension that I should use?

I tried initially dimension:user_id but I got 'Field user_id is not a valid dimension'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To query that data using the runReport method, you'll need to register "username" as a User-scoped custom dimension. There's documentation on that in [Custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209).

However, it's not recommended to register a high-cardinality dimension like a "username" as a custom definition; here are some best practice alternatives to consider: [Best practices for User-ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12675187).